# Intersection of the closed discs

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Let $D_n=D(x_n,r_n)$ be a sequence of closed discs in $\mathbb C$ with centre $x_n$ and radius $r_n$. Assume that $D_{n+1}\subseteq D_n$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n=r$ exist, and $D(x,r)=\bigcap_{n\geq 1}D_n$.

Obviously, the sequence $(r_n)$ is decreasing bounded below by $0$, so it converges to $r\geq 0$. How to see if $(x_n)$ converges? Drawing a figure, I think it must be true that $|x_n-x_{n+1}|\leq r_n-r_{n+1}$. I do not know how to prove it formally, could you help me out? If this is true, then we get
$$
|x_n-x_{n+p}|\leq \sum_{j=0}^{p-1}|x_{n+j}-x_{n+j+1}|\leq r_n-r_{n+p},
$$
and since the terms on the right hand side is Cauchy, the sequence $(x_n)$ must be Cauchy as well, and hence $(x_n)$ converges to $x\in\mathbb{C}$. How do you see if $x\in \bigcap_{n\geq 1}D_n$ and the last statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be enough to prove it for $D(x_{1}, r_{1}), D(x_{2}, r_{2}).$

If $x_{1} = x_{2}$ (trivial)

If $x_{1}\neq x_{2}$, define the line $\mathcal{L} = x_{1} + (x_{2} - x_{1})t, $ where $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

Then $\exists t\in \mathbb{R}: x_{1} + (x_{2} - x_{1})t\in D_{2}$. So, let's find a $t: \|x_{2} - [x_{1} + (x_{2} - x_{1})t] \| = r_{2}$, then $|1-t| = r_{2}/\|x_{2} -x_{1}\|.$ Thus $t = 1- r_{2}/\|x_{2} -x_{1}\|$ or $t = 1+ r_{2}/\|x_{2} -x_{1}\|$

So, for $t_{1} =  1+ r_{2}/\|x_{2} -x_{1}\|, x = x_{1} + (x_{2} - x_{1})t_{1}\in D_{2}$. Then $x\in D_{1},$ which conveys that $\|x_{1} -x\|\leq r_{1}$ and $\|x_{1} -x\|= \|x_{1} -x_{2}\| + r_{2}.$

Comment: Yes, that sequence of steps is to prove formally what you were trying to do.

Comment: OK. I finally understood it. Very smart to use a parametrization of the line through $x_1$ and $x_2$. If you have time, could you please answer the other questions stated in the post?

Comment: I will try. Thanks for verifying it.