# Intersection of the closed discs part 2

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

> Let $D_n=D(x_n,r_n)$ be a sequence of closed discs in $\mathbb C$ with centre $x_n$ and radius $r_n$. Assume that $D_{n+1}\subseteq D_n$. Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}r_n=r$ exist, and $D(x,r)=\bigcap_{n\geq 1}D_n$.

I asked in another [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3712703/intersection-of-the-closed-discs/3712774?noredirect=1#comment7636338_3712774), where I got an answer for the existence of the limit of $(x_n)$. Here, I need some help for the last part: $D(x,r)=\bigcap_{n\geq 1}D_n$. I spent hours thinking about it, but I fail to prove it, as I am dealing with an incredibly small disc or probably a point.

So far, I know is that, since $D_n$ is closed, we have that $x\in D_n$ for all $n\geq 1$, and hence $x\in \bigcap_{n\geq 1}D_n$. I feel like this has a connection to the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $0< \delta <r$ (if $r=0$ we skip this and do part 2 only); take $|x-y| \le \delta$

Then there is $n_0, |x_n-x| \le r-\delta, n \ge n_0$. It follows that $|x_n-y| \le r \le r_n, n \ge n_0$ so $y \in D_n , n \ge n_0$ hence $y \in F=\bigcap_{n\geq 1}D_n$

This means $D(x,\delta) \subset F, \delta <r$ which means that the interior of $D(x,r) \subset F$ (the open disc in other words) and since $F$ is closed, the closed disc $D(x,r) \subset F$

Now take $\delta >r$ and $|x-y|=\delta$; as before there is $n_0, r_{n_0} < r+\frac{\delta -r}{2}, |x_{n_0}-x| <\frac{\delta -r}{2}$.

But then $|x_{n_0}-y| \ge |x-y|-|x-x_{n_0}|>\delta-\frac{\delta -r}{2}=r+\frac{\delta -r}{2}>r_{n_0}$, so $y$ is not in $D(x_{n_0},r_{n_0})$ hence not in $F$, so the exterior of $D(x,r)$ is disjoint from $F$, so $F \subset D(x,r)$ and we are done!

Comment: By definition any point $y \in B(x,r)$ is at a distance $\delta(y)<r$ from $x$, so it is in a $D(x,\delta), \delta <r$

Comment: the union of **all** $D(x,\delta), \delta <r$ is $B(x,r)$ so yes individually each $D(x,\delta), \delta <r$ is contained in $B(x,r)$ and together they exhaust $B(x,r)$

Comment: Okay, it's making more sense. First, you proved that $D(x, \delta)\subseteq F$. Since $\delta\in (0,r)$ was arbitrary, we get $\bigcup_{0<\delta<r}D(x, \delta)\subseteq F$. But $\bigcup_{0<\delta<r}D(x, \delta)=B(x,r)$, proving one inclusion. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: correct as the comment is now - the other inclusion needs to be shown only for one $B_n$ (so in other words given some $|x-y|=\delta >r$, one needs to find one $B_n$ that doesn't contain $y$) - note that in both cases we avoid the $r$ case for simplicity, though it can be handled directly splitting the problem in two cases $r_n >r$ for all $n$ or $r_n=r, x_n=x$ from some $n$ on - it is a good exercise to show that those are the only two possibilities

Comment: Thank you so much. Haven't thought like this way before. When I read your proof for other inclusion, I thought if it could be done in another way as follows, please correct me if it's wrong: It is equivalent to show that the intersection of $\bigcap_{n}D_n$ and $\mathbb{C}\setminus D(x,r)$ is empty. Suppose not, i.e. $y$ belongs to both of these sets. Since $D(x_n,r/2)$ is inside $D(x_n,r_n)$, we choose $N$ such that $x\in D(x_N,r/2)$ and $y\in D(x_N,r/2)$. So $r<|x-y|\leq |x-x_N|+|x_N-y|\leq r$, contradiction. What do you think?

Comment: How do you know that $y \in D(x_N, r/2)$? it is not necessarily the case that for $y \in F$ we have $y-x_n \to 0$ - for example, if $x_n=x=0, r_n =1+1/n$ and $y=1-1/10000$ we definitely have $y \in F=D(0,1)$ but $|y-x_n| > 1/2$ for all $n$; we only know that $x_n \to x$ so indeed $|x_n-x|$ gets to be very small

Comment: What I just know is that $x\in F$ always. So, assuming $y\in F$ and $y\in \mathbb{C}\setminus D(x,r)$, we have $|x_n-y|\leq r_n$ for all $n\geq 1$ and $|x-y|>r$. What I desire to prove, is to show that $|x-y|\leq r$ to get a contradiction. At first, we get $|x-y|\leq |x-x_n|+|x_n-y|\leq 2r_n$ for all $n\geq 1$. Would it possible to make $N$ large, so that $|x_n-x|$ and $|x_n-y|$ are smaller than $r/2$ for all $n\geq N$? If not, is there a way to fix in this proof technique?

Comment: cannot do it that way - as $|x_n-y|$ is not necessarily that small; what you can do though is to make $|x_n-x|$ very small and then you need $|x_n-y|$ only to be at most $r_n$ since then you get $|x-y|$ to be at most $r_n+\epsilon$ which is at most $r+2\epsilon$ (taking large $n$ so $r_n \le r+\epsilon$) and then you use that $r+2\epsilon <|x-y|$ for $\epsilon$ small enough and $|x-y| >r$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, it helped me understand better. Appearntly, I liked your proof better. One last question for your answer. What you did was to prove that $\partial B(x,\delta)$ and $F$ are disjoint for every $\delta > r$, makes sense. Why would this imply that $D(x,r)^c$ and $F$ are disjoint? Is this simply because that we are looking at the points on the circle $\partial B(x,\delta)$, for all $\delta>r$, and all those circles are outside $D(x,r)^c$ completely, i.e. $\bigcup_{\delta>r}B(x,\delta)=D(x,r)^c$? Sorry for asking silly questions, I'm trying to understand

Comment: yes $\bigcup_{\delta>r}B(x,\delta)=D(x,r)^c$ (again it's easy to see this since (by definition) any point outside $D(x,r)$ must be at a distance $\delta >r$ from $x$, so allowing all such $\delta$ we cover all the points outside the disc